# Diagonal CSS3 Background Color/Images

Tags: html, css, diagonal

Basically I am trying to cut the background of a div off at an angle. Please see the image below for an example: You will notice that the navigation section is cut off and also the header image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4Rad.jpg

Is there a way to create this effect using CSS3? I have tried this:

```
.site-header {
    background-color: #0c3063;
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    @include clearfix;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;

    &:after {
        content: "";
        width: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -162px;
        right: -150px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: black;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        z-index: 2;
    }
}
```

In the example above it overlaps but I know how to fix this, basically just use before instead of after. However is there a better way of doing this?

My example seems I can not put the :after content before its parent so this solution is not ideal :( any ideas?

EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/6x3yenge/1/

Thanks

Comment: Could you create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: yea so you have done well whats the issue

Comment: The triangle overlaps the text. I fixed it now used an background image instead in the :after section of css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the following code does not achieve what you want for the image, it surely does the job for the top menu. Using borders to create triangles simplies things a lot.

JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/qvjhptpy/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="main"></div>
        <div class="cut"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    background: yellow;
}

.menu
{
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 0px;  /*In case a gap is coming between .main & .cut nested DIVs (Due to whitespace in HTML code)*/
}

.main
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.cut
{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid red;
}
```